# what is Difference between JPQL 2.1 's ON and Hibernate's WITH clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, hql, jpql

According to early draft version of `JPA 2.1` : https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_early_draft , It will include support for `ON` keyword in JPQL. 
In hibernate we already have `WITH` clause which does similar kind of job.

My question is would these two be the same or there are any differences?

Answer (score 1):

based on what I understand, "with" is just the replacement of "on" in hibernate. And the thing is hibernate does not even support "on" keyword in left join query. So I think it is safe to say that hibernate "with" keyword is equivalent to SQL "on" keyword.